# Prevent awk from interpeting variable contents?

Tags: bash, parsing, awk

I'm attempting to parse a make -n output to make sure only the programs I want to call are being called. However, awk tries to interpret the contents of the output and run (?) it. Errors are something like `awk: fatal: Cannot find file 'make'`. I have gotten around this by saving the output as a temporary file and then reading that into awk. However, I'm sure there's a better way; any suggestions?

EDIT: I'm using the output later in my script and would like to avoid saving a file to increase speed if possible.

Here's what isn't working:

```
my_input=$(make -n file)
my_lines=$(echo $my_input | awk '/bin/ { print $1 }') #also tried printf and cat
```

Here's what works but obviously takes longer than it has to because of writing the file:

```
make -n file > temp
my_lines=$(awk '/bin/ { print $1 }' temp)
```

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Doesn't `make -n file | grep bin` do what you want?

Comment: You need to quote the variable to preserve newlines: `echo "$my_input" | awk ...`

Comment: Thanks, glenn jackman. That fixed it! I knew I was missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly parse the output when it is generated by the following command and save the result in a file.

```
make -n file | grep bin > result.out
```

If you really want to go for an overkill awk solution, change your second line in the following way:

```
my_lines="$(awk '/bin/ { print }' temp)"
```